# Copy web page content with style

Tags: css, asp.net, css-float

I have a page and used lots of DIV elements and css for creating columns (used float,etc...) on it.
Now, our client is complaining that when they select the page content and paste it into the word document the style is broken; specially for those parts I used float.

I even tried paste with format but it's not working.

How can we copy and paste a web page content with it's correct style?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what browser your client uses? Browsers don't all support the same functionalities of CSS/html. You need to take that into account when writing your page.

Also, if you have a reference to an external stylesheet in your page, you need to also give it to your client.

Comment: Thanks for reply. They are using IE 8 and also I have a reference to an external stylesheet. is there any workaround to fix the issue instead of giving them the CSS file.

Comment: Yes, everything is working properly in IE8 and other IE versions and also browsers. The issue is happening only if they right click on the page and select some paragraphs and text (wrapped in DIV with Float) and paste it in any text editor (WORDS)